# Issue of display font beetween navigators

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am new to html css!
I have a problem with fonts not showing on Chrome and mozilla . I've tried on differents laptop but the font only work on my laptop.

I know im doing something wrong but can't find where..
My fonts are on a local folder.
Here is my css code:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat Light';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Fonts/montserrat/Montserrat Light'), url('Montserrat-Light.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat Medium';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Fonts/montserrat/Montserrat Medium'), url('Montserrat-Medium.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat SemiBold';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Fonts/montserrat/Montserrat SemiBold'), url('Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F9F9FD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.moi{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Montserrat-Light;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  right: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.texte{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Montserrat-light;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 168px;
  right: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Assets/img/favcon.png"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SCSS/styleP5.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="SCSS/Mediaqueries/MediaQueries-P5.css">

      <title>bla bla </title>
    </head>
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Fonts/montserrat/Montserrat Light'), url('Montserrat-Light.woff') format('woff');
}

.example {
    /* You need to have the same name in the @font-face font-family as in the font-family */
    /*           \/            \/*/
    font-family: Montserrat-Light;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

I renamed every font family with the same @fontface's name and now it seems to work on all navigators on my computer ( chrome, opera, mozilla), but when I try to open the website on an other computer's navigators it stills display a basic font with sherif.

Comment: ok I see what is wrong with it. You should change it to @font-face {font-family: Montserrat-Light;} You shouldn't have '' in font-family name.